# Where is the code for Spree Master Variant Creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using Spree's 3-0 Stable Backend. I know that Master Variant get created after a new product gets created, but I cannot find the file/code where the Master Variant code gets triggered.

The resource controller had pretty generic create code and a redirect to the Product's url. Does anyone know where/how the Master Variant gets created?

Answer (score 1):

Anddd, I found my own answer after posting. Funny how that works out.

For anyone in the future searching this, you have to look inside of the **core** gem rather than the backend. Variants get created after a Product gets created if the "option_values_hash" exists, which triggers the "build_variants_from_option_values_hash" method.

"Options_values_hash" and "build_variants_from_option_values_hash" can both be found at "spree/core/app/models/spree/product.rb ".